# Android creating ViewPropertyAnimator animation chain

Tags: android, animation, view

I'm trying this:

```
public void onClick(View view){
    tv.animate().x(600).y(100).scaleX(3).scaleY(3);
    tv.animate().x(400).y(1400).scaleX(1).scaleY(1);
}
```

but it skips the the first line of animation.
How can I make it chain them so first it will do the first line and then the next?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try this

```
 Runnable endAction = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         tv.animate().x(400).y(1400).scaleX(1).scaleY(1);
     }
 };

tv.animate().x(600).y(100).scaleX(3).scaleY(3).withEndAction(endAction);
```

as suggested in documentation.

Comment: withEndAction is only for API 16 and above

Comment: You can use a `AnimatorEventListener` instead of `.withEndAction()`.

Comment: `AnimatorEventListener` does not seem to be a public API. Is it ?

Comment: in this case, setStartDelay to last line adds start delay to endAction as well. I want no delay between animations

Comment: to use withEndAction you can also use ViewCompat: `ViewCompat.animate(tv).withEndAction(endAction)`